# Passing Material-UI Data Grid onSelectionChange to a react hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

When trying to send the selected rows of a Material-UI data-grid component to a React Hook, the site locks up with the following error:

```
Warning: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component calls setState inside useEffect, but useEffect either doesn't have a dependency array, or one of the dependencies changes on every render.
```

I may be going about it the wrong way, but what I'm hoping to do is pass the data of the currently selected rows into a React Hook so that I can action it.

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { DataGrid } from "@material-ui/data-grid";

const IndexPage = () => {
  const [test, setTest] = useState([]);

  function currentlySelected(selections) {
    setTest(selections);
    console.log(test);
  }

  const rows = [
    { id: 1, name: "Example 1", price: "$10.99" },
    { id: 2, name: "Example 2", price: "$12.50" }
  ];

  const columns = [
    { field: "name", headerName: "Name", width: 300 },
    { field: "price", headerName: "Price" }
  ];

  const sortModel = [
    {
      field: "name",
      sort: "asc"
    }
  ];

  return (
    <>
      <div style={{ height: "50vh" }}>
        <DataGrid
          sortingOrder={["desc", "asc"]}
          sortModel={sortModel}
          rows={rows}
          columns={columns}
          pageSize={100}
          rowHeight={38}
          checkboxSelection
          onSelectionChange={newSelection => {
            console.log(newSelection.rows)

            // **** The following line breaks the page upon selection **** 
            // currentlySelected(newSelection)
          }}
        />
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default IndexPage;
```

Inside of the `DataGrid` you'll notice an `onSelectionChange` property with some commented out code. Uncommenting that line, allowing for the `onSelectionChange` to update the `test` React Hook is what causes the page to break.

What is the proper way of pushing the currently selected fields up to a hook?

[Code Sandbox Example Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/infallible-mayer-ogutq?file=/src/App.js).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is happening is when you render `DataGrid` it is most firing `onSelectionChange`.  From there, you are setting your state which re-renders the grid, which calls `onSelectionChange`... and you are into an infinite loop.

You can fix this by either:

1. Only calling `setTest` if selections passed by `onSelectionChange` does not equal what you have in state already.

```
const IndexPage = () => {
  const [test, setTest] = useState([]);

  function currentlySelected(selections) {
    if (test !== selections) { // I didn't write it in but you'll need to do object comparison here
      setTest(selections)
    }
  }

 ...

  return (
    <div style={{ height: "50vh" }}>
      <DataGrid
        onSelectionChange={currentlySelected}
      />
    </div> 
  )
}
```

2. Store the selected row in a ref

```
const IndexPage = () => {
  const test= useRef({});

  function currentlySelected(selections) {
    test.current = selections;
  }

 ...

  return (
    <div style={{ height: "50vh" }}>
      <DataGrid
        onSelectionChange={currentlySelected}
      />
    </div> 
  )
}
```

Option 2 may or may not make sense depending on what you want to do with the selected rows, but either of these should stop your page from locking up

Comment: Setting the data to the ref did work for my use case, thank you!